How to decide making an exception against our community rules
As a community, we agreed on many subjects, on-off topics, homework questions, etc.
In a recent question, our one of venerable user gave an answer with the comment

Well, we generally don't analyze crypto here (especially crypto that has been expressed just as code without explination), however I'll make an exception here.

Should we make exceptions against our community rules? If so, when?
note : post deleted by the asker.

No we should not allow exceptions.
However, sometimes somebody wants to give a quick comment which doesn't fit the comment boxes. Generally we can allow both such comments and answers - for the time being.
However: please do not upvote or downvote either question or answer but just hit the close button below the question. I don't think that is too different from what should be happening normally, and it is very similar to how we handle homework questions.
As a mod (at the time of writing) you might find me dallying a bit to allow for comments to stream in, so that the user can be pointed in the right direction. As mod any vote close is pretty final after all.
If too many off topic questions stream in - especially from the same users - we might have to reconsider our way of handling comments / answers for them.

Created a third option as this answer is relatively opinionated / non objective, so I don't think it fits the generic "No" vote that well.


Yes, we should

fill the reasons, community!.





No, we shouldn't

fill the reasons, community!.



